# Minimize, Maximize button disappear without any reason

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, desktop-application

[image]

It's a dialog based MFC application. I didn't intentionally add any code about the Minimize, Maximize and Restore button. It can show those button at the first. But it just disappear after long time running. Or maybe sleep of the computer causes this?

I have no idea about this, do you have any clue?

Edited:
Thanks @xMRi's remind, I checked its style, seems still to be right.
[image]

Comment: There is always a reason. That's axiomatic. If you get into that frame of mind, the problem will be simpler to solve.

Comment: only your window buttons disappear or every window ?

Comment: Did the program do anything in the meantime? Have you reproduced the bug while making sure that it doesn't? Have you tried to reproduce the bug with a new project, like maybe an unchanged example project? We need to rule out that this is a problem with your computer itself.

Comment: Use SPY++ and check if anyone changes the windows style....

Comment: Maybe some resource leak is causing this, GDI or user resource. Are they completely missing or just invisible but respond to clicks?

Comment: @Aziuth, Yes, I use it to do some clipboard operations.

Comment: @santoshdhanawade, only those window buttons on my application.

Comment: @AlexanderGutenev, completely missing. I tried to click on there, nothing happened.

Comment: What happens if you create an all new MFC project?

Comment: @Zhang still waiting for feedback to my previous comment and to  Aziuth's comment.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Sorry. I always have several MFC applications for tests. But maybe they didn't run for long time, so no such a symptom. I think santosh dhanawade's answer may be right. It's a system problem. Next time, If I come across this bug, I'll restart the windows desktop manager to take a try. Thank you for concern.

Comment: @Jabberwocky, PS, there is a method - I gave it as an answer - for restore system buttons that didn't work for my missing-system-buttons application. So I think it's a system problem.

Comment: Can you make [Minimum Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi guys, this malfunction disappeared unexpectedly after I unintently solved several dangling pointers. Actually, I used several lambda expressions for hot-key responsible functions. Those lambda were released after out of the scope. I changed them to static solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Listed below few possible reason & resolution may impact you application look. More specifically, your device manager plays important role in application appearance. I would say its environment or certain unnecessary application(Virus)installation issue rather than your MFC application issue.

[Full Fix: Minimize, Maximize and Close Buttons Disappear](https://windowsreport.com/minimize-maximize-close-buttons-disappear/)

Answer (score 0):

At least I know a way to restore the disappared system buttons.

```
ModifyStyle(0, WS_MINIMIZEBOX);
GetSystemMenu(FALSE)->InsertMenu(-1, MF_BYPOSITION, SC_MINIMIZE, _T("Minimize"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Press F11 for Windows 10, or right-click on the application which you can't see windows button then choose view finally uncheck the full screen